# Using Google Analytics without sending query string data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We're doing a simple implementation of Google Analytics on our ASP.NET with jQuery/AJAX web, and for most of it we just call _trackPageview and let Google do the rest.

We do a lot of data transfer in query strings, and recently, management became concerned that a lot of our data (such as product numbers) would be sent to Google.  Without discussing whether that should be a concern:

Is it possible to use Google Analytics at all without *sending* the query string to Google's servers?  I know how to filter it out from the actual reports, but I'm looking for a way to prevent it from being sent over the wire at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as Litso said, you can send a whatever you want as the pathname for a GA page-view, but you'll want to automate the process with JavaScript.

The following code will take the current URL's pathname (which excludes the query string) and uses it as the pagename value.

```
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname ]);
```

Or, conversely, if you're using the old _gat code,

```
  pageTracker._trackPageview(location.pathname);
```

So, if your URL is http://example.com/path/to/page.html?supersecretinfo, it will get tracked in GA as /path/to/page.html

Comment: Just tested in IE without any trouble. You can see it alerted out here: http://htmlto.com/redirect/alert.php?supersecretparameter

Answer (score 3):

In stead of automatically tracking the pageview, you can use

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/dir/example.html');
```

You'll have to dynamically strip out the parameters off of the url of each page. I'm not sure how to do that but it's definitely possible with JavaScript.