# Strip query parameters from url before sending to google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, query-string

I am using the standard Google analytics snippet on pages to send info to google analytics.

For various reasons, my page is arrived at with a query parameter.

In an ideal world, this would not be the case but it is not a perfect world so instead **I must avoid it being sent to google analytics as it contains personal information**.

I have tried the following:

1. What was suggested here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3669333/2295284, as follows:  ((I am so sorry the formatting is really not playing ball D:)

   `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname ]);`

   ```
   (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
       i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
       i[r]=i[r]||function() {
           (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)
       }, i[r].l=1*new Date();
       a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
       a.async=1;
       a.src=g;
       m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
   ga('create', '@gaToken', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
   ```

I have been manually adding a query parameter to the url and using ObservePoint to check the content.  The Content Information contains a Document Location URL of "http://localhost/my/url/page?uiop=qwert"... which appears to mean that the _gaq.push line isn't doing anything at all.

2. I tried digging into the function and manually changing the url, but it just resulted in an endless loop of page refreshing:

   (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
   alert(i.location.href);
   var locn = i.location.href.indexOf("?")
   i.location.href = i.location.href.substring(0, locn)
   i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
   i[r]=i[r]||function() {
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)
   }, i[r].l=1*new Date();
   a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
   a.async=1;
   a.src=g;
   m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');ga('create', '@gaToken', 'auto');
3. I do not have access to Tag Manager, which I thought might be an option based on the following:  http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/17/strip-query-parameters-google-analytics/

Any suggestions would be very greatly appreciated, am rather at the end of my wits :(

(Apologies for the formatting, it was not co-operating :(

Comment: You can also leave the tracking code unchanged an remove the query strings via a filter within the GA view.

Comment: Yes, but I need to prevent it going to GA in the first place because I don't have the ability to filter out our query string everywhere on ga.

Comment: In that case @dorians answer is the correct one (it's even part of the official docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#pageview_fields) and you need to figure out why it is not working. Is there a chance that maybe your debugger is playing tricks on you ? Try the GA debugger, or Google Tag Assistant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first option is the correct one, but the code you used is for a previous version of Google Analytics.

Instead, replace `ga('send', 'pageview');` with `ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);` See the [page tracking documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overview) for reference.

Comment: No joy :(  I have updated option 1 in my question with the full code I have tried and the resulting content according to ObservePoint

Comment: This is how I send pageviews, to get "clean" pageview data in GA. A question I've always had - will this have any impact on traffic with utm parameters like utm_campaign and utm_medium? Or are those parameters automatically recorded by the GA snippet regardless of what is sent in `ga('send', 'pageview')` ...

Comment: Good question. I'd say the parameters are not affected, as you override the `page` field and not the `location` field. The latter contains the full URL, `page` is only used for the path segment. But I think you'd need to run a test to know for sure.

Comment: @dorian - set up a test of this and you are correct, utm parameters are not impacted, even when only sending pathname.

Comment: Would love to see a new answer to work with the google tag manager, which seems to be the default configuration for GA now

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Google Tag Manager: in the setup for the tag, there's an option called 'Fields to set', where you can manually edit any of the information that's being sent to Google Analytics (note that this happens locally, so would solve your data protection problem).

Here's an example where I've manually edited the 'Page field', which is what you need to do. In this case, I've chosen a pair of custom variables to feed in, but you'll probably need a custom JavaScript variable that takes the standard {{Page Path}} variable (which is what would be fed by default) and returns everything preceeding the first question mark.

[image: Replacing the 'page' field]

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access to Tag Manager :(

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you don't have access to it? It's a separate tool from Google Analytics, and you can set up an account attached to any email address.

Comment: But how does it link in with google analytics?  What about if I left the team?  It is not something that is used anywhere else in the organisation and I feel like there must be a simpler way of doing this up without having to set up another system to do it...

Comment: It links in with Google Analytics because you choose to deploy Google Analytics on it. From within GTM you can assign permissions to other people, and you should always use your work email for GTM accounts anyway, so that there's no risk of being left attached to something. Yes, it's a bit of a leap to GTM, but its free, and will solve your problems.